# What's the matter this error when register to the apple's appstore?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new in Objective-C. 
I struggled to deal with error when registered to the appstore. I had first time to register to the appstore so I don't know what can I do this. Error occured too much but I write to sum up this. I masked private information with 'x'.

======================log======================

2017-07-11 10:34:09 +0000  Rejecting:  (Offending Keys: (
    "beta-reports-active" ))

2017-07-11 10:34:09 +0000  Filtering based on profile type: app-store

2017-07-11 10:34:09 +0000  Accepting:

2017-07-11 10:34:09 +0000  Accepting:

2017-07-11 10:34:09 +0000  selecting top entry in sorted array: ("",""
)

2017-07-11 10:34:19 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Symbols tool failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Symbols tool failed}

2017-07-11 10:34:22 +0000 [MT] Proceeding to distribution step IDEDistributionResultViewController, context: ', distributionTask(resolved)='1', distributionMethod(resolved)='', teamID(resolved)='xxxxxxxx'>
    Chain (10, self inclusive):
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    ', distributionMethod='', teamID='(null)'>

2017-07-11 10:34:22 +0000 [MT] Upload failed for archive com.sbi.mid.iOS with issues:("~~~~~~")

Comment: Are you trying to upload an application developed with beta Xcode or beta Macos?

Comment: I heard first time that beta Xcode and beta Macos. Search that first, and then I'll try this. Thank you for answer on my question.